# Cassandra's poorly design of table naming convention

Tags: python, cassandra

Let `a = "03bb2997_8b7a_4359_800d_7c14e5175bc9"` and I decide to make it a table name of my cassandra. Hence, by using Python,

```
session.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "%s" (date date, time time, input text, predicted_result text, PRIMARY KEY(date, time));""" % new_modelId)
```

Take note of the double quotes between %s, without it, the cql will complain `SyntaxException: line 1:35 mismatched character '_' expecting '-'` since the table name cannot start with numeric character

The table is created successfully. I verified it through cqlsh. However, when I try to insert data into the table with code below:

```
session.execute("""INSERT INTO "%s" (date, time, input, predicted_result) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s);""",
                        (a, str(dateTime.date()), str(dateTime.time()),
                         json.dumps(json.loads(input_json)["0"]), json.dumps(json.loads(predicted_result_json)["0"])))
```

`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table '03bb2997_8b7a_4359_800d_7c14e5175bc9'"`

I tried with hardcoded table name and it works.

```
session.execute("""INSERT INTO "03bb2997_8b7a_4359_800d_7c14e5175bc9" (date, time, input, predicted_result) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s);""",
                        ( str(dateTime.date()), str(dateTime.time()),
                         json.dumps(json.loads(input_json)["0"]), json.dumps(json.loads(predicted_result_json)["0"])))
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with Cassandra table naming. It is so confusing and frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot parameterize keyspace or table name, only the parameters on prepared statements. How you execute it here is not a prepared statement, but your arguments to execute have been confused with how you put your parentheses. You are putting a with the first arg as part of a tuple, so I think it would work to:

```
session.execute("""INSERT INTO "%s" (date, time, input, predicted_result) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s);""",
                        a,
                        str(dateTime.date()),
                        str(dateTime.time()),
                        json.dumps(json.loads(input_json)["0"]),
                        json.dumps(json.loads(predicted_result_json)["0"])))
```

Also, you can always build string yourself as well:

```
session.execute("""INSERT INTO "%s" (date, time, input, predicted_result) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');""" %
                        (a,
                        str(dateTime.date()),
                        str(dateTime.time()),
                        json.dumps(json.loads(input_json)["0"]),
                        json.dumps(json.loads(predicted_result_json)["0"]))))
```

Generally its good practice to have hard coded table names for security implications.

As an aside, are you creating tables dynamically? This will eventually cause issues. Cassandra doesn't do well if it has thousands of tables and loading schema gets slower and slower as you make alterations (uses STCS).

Comment: I tried with the string building method ( on the 2nd ) and error came out `SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:104 mismatched input '-09' expecting ')' (... input, predicted_result) VALUES(2017[-09]-19...)">
`  However, I appreciate the kind reminder of good practice!

Comment: right, would need to put `'` around the `%s`'s in the VALUES section depending on type etc

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem by using an ugly way.

```
query = "INSERT INTO " + a
session.execute(query + """ (date, time, input, predicted_result) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s);""", (
            str(dateTime.date()), str(dateTime.time()), json.dumps(json.loads(input_json)["0"]),
            json.dumps(json.loads(predicted_result_json)["0"])))
```